# create a ListView diagrammatically

Tags: android, android-layout

in onCreate:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setId(1);
ListView lView = new ListView(this);
String[] lStr = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };
ArrayAdapter<String> lAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, tv.getId(), lStr);
lView.setAdapter(lAdap);
setContentView(lView);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dtl/com.example.dtl.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems You're using [public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29) here `textViewResourceId` - The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.
In Your code it's not that id. You need resource ID, not view Id. I'm suggesting to checkout some adapter examples (e.g. [this one](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/how-to-create-a-listview-using-arrayadapter-in-android/))

Answer (score 0):

try to use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` instead of `textview`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
YourList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, YourArray));
```